# Is there data available comparing neutrinos of different flavor scattering on hadrons?

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, neutrinos, leptons

I'm looking for data (ideally in the form of visually striking plots) **comparing** the scattering of neutrinos of different mass eigenstates ([flavors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_(particle_physics)#Leptons)) (or perhaps also, or instead, of different [weak eigenstates](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%22weak+eigenstate%22&title=Special:Search&profile=default&fulltext=1&searchToken=bc9cpfbdlsne6exwfr19mvvl1)), on hadrons.

(Token of previous research: As far as I have been able to find out there is no such plot included in ["*The PDG Review: 50. Neutrino Cross Section Measurements*"](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2016/reviews/rpp2016-rev-nu-cross-sections.pdf) which appears focussed on data and plots about muon neutrinos $\nu_{\mu}$.)

Comment: the reason there are independent muon_neutrino and electron_neutrino studies is the energy difference in the source which gives the neutrino. Muon neutrino antineutrono beams could be manipulated in the accelerators. Electron_neutrinos are in the energy ranges of nuclear physics, and in reactors. see http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1960PhRv..117.1614K .

Comment: @anna v: "_the reason there are independent muon_neutrino and electron_neutrino studies is [...]_" -- There've even been plans of [tau neutrino studies](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22tau+neutrino+neutral+current%22&*); cmp. [IceCube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IceCube_Neutrino_Observatory); over some shared range of "incoming neutrino energy", which makes a useful [abscissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abscissa) for nice plots. "_Muon neutrino antineutrono beams could be manipulated in the accelerators._" -- Surely (anti-)muon beams can. Then: what about the $\nu_e$ portion?

Comment: All these beams start from hadronic decays, and the pion has a very small branching ratio to electron. look at this for accelerator beams. https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0609129

Comment: @anna v: "_arxiv.org/abs/physics/0609129_" -- Ah, thanks. (Above, I had thought of muons as source of $\nu_{\mu}$; while, as I now learned, the actual practice is to take mesons directly as $\nu_{\mu}$-sources, even though this requires substantial "muon filters".) Fig. 27 does show some $\nu_e$ contributions after all; but surely that's still a long way from obtaining NC-scattering results.

Comment: A neutrino beam generated from muon decay would have a roughly equal mixture of $\nu_\mu$ and $\bar{\nu}_e$ (or the conjugate) which would be more difficult to analyze for oscillation effects.

Comment: In the two body decays into mu-nu, if one knows the muon track one knows where the neutrino track has to be  and thus a rough beam can be manipulated